# yii2 twig child extends, parent layout output twice

Tags: yii2, twig

I'm Twig beginner. I currently try to setup Yii2 layout with Twig.

I having 3 Twig file.

base.twig

```
{{ this.beginPage() }}
<!DOCTYOE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="{{ app.language }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="{{ app.charset }}" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{ html.encode(this.title) }}</title>
    {{ this.head() }}
    {{ html.csrfMetaTags() | raw }}
</head>
<body>
    {{ this.beginBody() }}
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    {{ this.endBody() }}
</body>
</html>
{{ this.endPage() }}
```

cp.twig

```
{% extends '_layouts/base.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="cp">
        {% block header %}{% endblock %}
        <hr />
        {% block content %}
            {{ content }}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

index.twig

```
{% extends '_layouts/cp.twig' %}

{% block header %}this is header{% endblock %}
```

After I render from my Yii2 controller `return $this->render('index');` then it come out very weird output:

```
<!DOCTYOE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="z_y1CPsfUBwHE6uC3dHg225wVQ8i2-eGhZa9f55Qrm39nYI6gk0TdVJ6nruf5q6WJAcCaUGolPWo9fxM_TrNHA==">

</head>
<body>
    
            <div class="cp">
                <hr />
                    
<!DOCTYOE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link href="/mlaxology/yii2/workspace/projects/pawscms/web/assets/903cba57/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="z_y1CPsfUBwHE6uC3dHg225wVQ8i2-eGhZa9f55Qrm39nYI6gk0TdVJ6nruf5q6WJAcCaUGolPWo9fxM_TrNHA==">

</head>
<body>
    
            <div class="cp">
        this is header        <hr />
                    
            </div>
    
</body>
</html>

            </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

It output unexpected duplicated parent layout.

My objective is to create a dynamic layout header which can be override by child layout with Twig `{% block header %}{% endblock %}` command. I know there is other way to solve this issue, like using Twig variable to store the dynamic header. But I like they way what {% block %} does.

I'm wondering why `base.twig` `{% block body %}{% endblock %}` working properly but `index.twig` having repeat content issue ....

I already spend 2 days on this, try googling but no similar issue can be found ... finally I think I really need stackoverflow help.

Sorry for my English and thanks for reading this :)

## My ugly way to solve this issue :

base.twig:

```
{% if content is defined %}{{ content | raw }}{% else %}
{{ void(this.beginPage()) }}
<!DOCTYOE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="{{ app.language }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="{{ app.charset }}" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{ html.encode(this.title) }}</title>
    {{ this.head() }}
    {{ html.csrfMetaTags() | raw }}
</head>
<body>
    {{ this.beginBody() }}
        {%- block body %}{% endblock %}
    {{ this.endBody() }}
</body>
</html>
{{ void(this.endPage()) }}
{% endif %}
```

After several debug ... this happen because reprint `content`, so I wrap with `{% if content is defined %}{{ content | raw }}{% else %}` for temp fix.

Any better way to solve this issue?

Comment: Looking in the [examples](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-twig/doc/guide/2.0/en/layouts-and-widgets#main-layout) of `yii2` it's seem u need to wrap `void` arround `this.beginPage()` and such. What u are trying to do is certainly possible in a standalone twig environment. See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/cx9j5w)

Comment: Thanks for reply @DarkBee. I had tried wrap with `void` and having same issue. I think maybe is my Yii2 structure issue.

Comment: Do note its `<!DOCTYPE html>` and not `<!DOCTYOE html>`

Comment: Thanks for point out this spelling mistake, I just corrected. But the issue still happen haha. Anyway really thanks for reply.